# Skip current dag run if previous instance dag run is in running state

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag which will be scheduled every hour. Let's say 01:00am, 02:00am, 03:00am. Let's say 02:00am is picked, but if 01:00am dag run is stil in progress, need to cancel 02:00am instance.

Am trying this code.

```
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Chicago")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 15, tzinfo=local_tz),
    'run_as_user': user_id
}

dag = DAG(os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".pyc", "").replace(".py", ""),
          catchup=False,
          max_active_runs=1
          schedule_interval='0 * * * *',  #schedule_interval='@hourly'
          default_args=default_args
)

def check_prev_dag_run_status(**kwargs):
    curr_dag_id = kwargs['dag'].dag_id
    curr_task_id = kwargs['task'].task_id
    newdate = kwargs['execution_date']
    ti = TaskInstance(curr_dag_id, curr_task_id, newdate)
    state = ti.current_state()
    if state=="running":
        raise ValueError("Not all previous tasks successfully completed")
        
check_success_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_status',
    python_callable= check_prev_dag_run_status,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

run_this_0 = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_shell',
        bash_command="ksh runshellscript.ksh",
        execution_timeout=None,
        dag=dag 
  )
```

I have been getting error message that

**[2020-11-17 12:30:07,337] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 'dag_id'**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/airflow/bd/pyenv/pycdr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)

File "/airflow/bd/pyenv/pycdr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
return_value = self.execute_callable()

File "/airflow/bd/pyenv/pycdr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_ca

*Please suggest me

1. what am missing while passing arguments to airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance
2. Does execution_date give the immediate previous instance of the dag run?
   or how to get the immediate previous instance dag run state*

Comment: execution_date gives you the execution date of the current DAG run, not the previous run, see also [Airflow Scheduler](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html)

Comment: Am actually looking for what am missing while passing arguments to airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance` just takes two arguments, `task` and `execution_date`, not 3 as in your code. Additionally `task` is not the `task_id` but rather the defined task, in your example it's `run_this_0` I guess. You need to pass the `execution_date` of the last task run, not the current one. Also the status can be different from running and still unsuccessful, so I would also change this.

Putting all this together, the following code should be fine to check if `run_this_0` of the previous DAG Run succeeded:

```py
def check_prev_dag_run_status(**kwargs):
    newdate = kwargs['prev_execution_date']
    ti = TaskInstance(run_this_0, newdate)
    state = ti.current_state()
    if state!="success":
        raise ValueError("Not all previous tasks successfully completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [task concurreny](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html) to 1 for this task. Newer task will not run unless previous run has not started.

Set [depend on past](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules)  true. This has drawback that if one batch fails, next batches will not run.

Use external task sensor with mode reschedule to wait for earlier batch to complete.